# In an open set, all points are a positive distance away from the complement [proof verification]

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Proposition: Let $(X,\text{dist})$ be a metric space and $O\subseteq X$ be an open set and let $$d:O\to \mathbb{R}^+_0:x\mapsto d(x) = \inf\{\text{dist}(x,y)\mid y\in O^c\}.$$
> Then for all $x\in O:d(x)>0$.

My proof:

Suppose there is an $x\in O$ such that $d(x) = 0$. Then surely this is not a reached minimum over $\{\text{dist}(x,y)\mid y\in O^c\}$, because then there would be a $y\in O^c$ such that $\text{dist}(x,y) = 0$. But then $x=y$, which is a contradiction. So there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of elements in $O^c$ such that $x_n\to x$. But, since $O$ is open, $O^c$ is closed, which would imply that $x\in O^c$, which is again a contradiction.

Comment: Simpler: If $x \in O$ then $B(x, r) \subset O$ for some $r > 0$, and therefore $d(x) \ge r$.

Comment: But $\inf\limits_{x\in O}d(x)=0$ again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct (good work!). An alternative approach is this: take $x\in O$. Then, since $O$ is open, there is some $r>0$ such that $B_r(x)\subset O$. In other words, if $y\in O^\complement$, then $d(x,y)\geqslant r$. But then $d(x)\geqslant r$. In particular, $d(x)\ne0$.

Comment: Ofcourse! This is much more straightforward. Thanks.